# VS2017 - StartUp project with dependent projects fails unless all projects start first

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have 3 projects in my solution:

1. Console App (Client)
2. IdentityServer
3. Web API (asp.net core 2.2)

StartUp Project:  Console App (Client)
Dependent Projects:  IdentityServer and Web API

Error received when I hit Ctrl-F5:
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

However, this error no longer appears and the above set-up works fine if I first run all 3 as "Multiple StartUp Projects".

Why does VS2017 work this way?  Or is this symptomatic of a configuration I am overlooking?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with VS, it is your OS that works this way.  When a program connects to the machine but nobody is listening on the port then it tells it to sod off.  You found a workaround, happens to work because the server started quicker than the client.  Another one is to run VS twice, one to debug the server and another to debug the client.

Comment: Thank you Hans.  This makes perfect sense, though for Windows users, it would seem to encourage creating everything under a single project (vs. multiple) for more seamless testing.

Comment: I'm guessing it is something in you `app.config`. The web API port, for example, can be configured in the Web API app.config, and when you launch you Web API from another project, he get another port. Just example